# How do I convert an InputStream to S3ObjectInputStream in Java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, inputstream, fileinputstream

I want to convert a `FileInputStream` to a `S3ObjectInputStream`.

This is my current code:

```java
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
S3ObjectInputStream sObject = (S3ObjectInputStream)is;
```

However, it's giving the error:

```
java.io.FileInputStream cannot be cast to com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream
```

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You need cast as a `InputStream`

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
S3ObjectInputStream sObject = (InputStream) is;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Is it possible to do the opposite? Can I convert S3ObjectInputStream to FileInputStream?

Comment: This gives a `ClassCastException`. How is this answer accepted?

Comment: No, actually, the code won't even compile. You can't assign an `InputStream` to `S3ObjectInputStream` And the cast is redundant... `is` is already declared to be `InputStream`..

Answer (score 6):

Use the below constructor to convert an `InputStream` to a `S3ObjectInputStream`:

```java
var s3ObjectInputStream = new S3ObjectInputStream(inputStream, null);
```

You can safely use `null` for the 2nd argument in the constructor ([`HttpRequestBase`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream.html#S3ObjectInputStream-java.io.InputStream-org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase-)) as the `abort` method which uses it, isn't available in the cast `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor

```java
new S3ObjectInputStream(InputStream in, ...
```

I used aws-java-sdk version 1.11.526