# How do I convert String to S3ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, amazon-s3, inputstream, ioutils

In one of the APIs, `S3Object` is converted to `String` using Apache IOUtils using the below steps:

```java
S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
String streamString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
```

In the other API, when I have to convert the string back to `S3ObjectInputStream`, I try the following steps, but it doesn't seem to work:

**Approach 1:**

```java
String streamString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream); // --> from the 1st API

S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream = new S3ObjectInputStream
        (new ByteArrayInputStream(streamString.getBytes()), null); --> Returning an incorrect/null inputstream
```

**Approach 2:**

```
String streamString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream); // --> from the 1st API

InputStream sampleStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(streamString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Is there any other way to convert it correctly without losing data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an InputStream to S3ObjectInputStream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444766/how-do-i-convert-an-inputstream-to-s3objectinputstream-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it works alright.  Your issue probably lies somewhere else (probably your `inputStream`).

*Here is the working code (with your code included)*.

```
@Test
  public void testS3ObjectInputStream() throws IOException {

    String originalString = "Hello World";
    InputStream inputStream =
        new ByteArrayInputStream(originalString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   
     // your code
    String streamString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream =
        new S3ObjectInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(streamString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), null);

    assertNotNull(s3ObjectInputStream); //PASSES!

    String recoveredString = IOUtils.toString(s3ObjectInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    assertEquals(originalString, recoveredString); //PASSES!
  }
```